# Может ли метод проверять объект вместо массива?

Tags: java, ооп, for

В ниже приведенном коде метод `checkForPresence()` должен в качестве параметра принимать группу, а не массив. Как это сделать?

```
public class Professor extends Group {

    Professor(String groupCode, Students[] studentsList) {
        super(groupCode, studentsList);
    }
    AbstractCheck auditForStudent;

    public AbstractAudit checkForPresence() {
        System.out.println("Проверка наличия студентов группы " + getGroupCode() + ":");
        for (Students audit : getStudentsInGroup()) {
            if (audit.isPresent())
                auditForStudent = new Present();
            else
                auditForStudent = new Absent();
        }
        System.out.println(auditForStudent.checkForPresence());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: в нижеприведенном коде метод checkForPresence() вообще ничего не принимает. А каком масииве идет речь и о какой группе. Вы имеете ввиду супер класс? конкретизируйте вопрос

Comment: Да, принимать должен супер-класс. Хотя может можно обойтись и без наследования класса Group, но главное, чтобы метод проверял объект, а не массив.

Answer (score 2):

Профессор (`Professor`) не является группой (`Group`), он только работает с ней. Следовательно, наследование здесь не нужно, но подойдет композиция.

`Professor` принимает группу с которой будет работать (в реальности, это тоже должен быть список и он может быть изменен `Professor`ом или `Deparment`ом).

```
class Group {

    private String id;
    private Student[] list;

    // getters & setters

}
```

У `Group` есть `id` и нам не нужно передавать его отдельно в конструктор `Professor`а.

```
class Professor {

    private Group group;

    public Professor(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public AbstractAudit checkForPresence() {
        System.out.println("Проверка наличия студентов группы " + group.getId() + ":");

        for (Student student : group.getList()) {
            ...
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: ругается на цикл

Comment: @Никита,  почему?

Comment: Во-первых, я не знаю что нужно подставить в методе main вместо group. Во-вторых, main хочет массив от Students, а в Professor ссылка на Group.

Comment: @Никита, сначала создайте групу и заполните ее. Тогда получить массив просто - `group.getList()`

Comment: @Никита, после этого передайте ссылку `group` в конструктор `Professor`

Comment: заработало. Спасибо. То у меня голова квадратная от Java была))

Comment: @Никита если ответ помог, Вы можете проголосовать "за" или принять его.

Comment: я за, только не знаю как.

Comment: А, уже разобрался)